# GCP: how to transfer a model to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project, transfer

I have a Natural Language model (within a data set) in a certain project in GCP.

How can I move these dataset and its model to another project?

Comment: Where is stored your model?

Comment: Are you using Natural Language API or AutoML Natural Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you are using AutoML Natural Language. There is not a direct mechanism to migrate the model to another project. Nevertheless, there is a current [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/162381938) for this functionality, you can upvote the PIT for demonstrate your interest.

The only available option I can think of is [exporting the dataset](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/manage-datasets#export-dataset) from the existing project, import the dataset and retrain your model in the new project.